# Separating a word from a line

Tags: shell

I have a issue, I want to extract a word from a line which is not separted by coma or something. Here's the example,

```
str1 = abc

less file1.txt | grep -i $str1
```

I am getting the output as

> <resultset = abcdef, aabcdef, frwfwr, qewrtyt, bfwrtw />

I want to separate the "abcdef" from the above line. How to do that?

Comment: Specifically which shell are you using? Answers may vary depending on that.

Comment: Bash... anyways, the logic would do..

Comment: why you want to extract `abcdef` instead of `aabcdef`? because it is the first match?

Answer (score 0):

> str1=abc # or anything that you want
>
> str2="$str1"[a-zA-Z0-9]* #appending regex for aphabets and number if you want to match numbers you match them here
>
> grep -i "$str2" /tmp/b # or your way less file1.txt | grep -i $str2

let me know if this works